# Internet Communication Error: Using Tableau to Access BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

I can successfully connect to a table in BigQuery (using Tableau), and built out some viz's at a high level. Once I start trying to leverage data at the detail (user records) in Tableau, I get the following error 'Internal communication error: SSL Connect (www.googleapis.com)'

It's as is the connection works for awhile at the high level, but as soon as I try to connect to more records, it breaks.

The expected results is that the connection allows me to use all dimensions and measures in tableau as needed.

Comment: Just for more context: Is this Tableau Desktop or Server? Published datasource or connecting directly? Have you talked to IT about this error - there's a chance theres a proxy in between Tableau and the internet that is limiting the size/duration of responses. Also, take note that GoogleAPIs have limitations on data response size/duration. Are you working with billions of records or something very large? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas

Comment: Also, when the error occurs does it occur at a specific amount of time (ie: always at the 60, 90, 600, etc second mark?)